# Is there any way to export the effective policy assigned to API and operation level to an XML file?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

I tried below option, but its not fetching the effective policy assigned to an API or operation, where as its fetching just the policy assigned to them alone

```
curl --location 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/xxxxxxxxxx/apis/apiname/policies/policy?format=xml&api-version=2022-08-01' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below URL to find out the effective policy in **API level**.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/apis/{apiId}/policies/policy?effective=true&format=xml&api-version=2022-08-01
```

**CURL Request**-

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0e************" "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/apis/{apiId}/policies/policy?effective=true&format=xml&api-version=2022-08-01"
```

I am getting below response-

[image]

To get the effective policy in **operation level**, you can use the below URL.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/apis/{apiId}/operations/{operationId}/policies/policy?effective=true&format=xml&api-version=2022-08-01
```

**CURL Request**-

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eX******" "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/{apiId}/operations/{operationId}/policies/policy?effective=true&format=xml&api-version=2022-08-01"
```

**Response**-

[image]

Comment: Great.. Its giving the effective policy associated with the api and operation. Further one more query that can we amend some additional policy to the extracted policy.xml and apply the new policy to the API or operation without duplicating them ?